# iceprog .. Can't find iCE FTDI USB device (Linux permission issue??)

Tags: linux, yosys

I recently installed yosys on Ubuntu 15.1 (32-bit Arm-7 machine) and I compiled my first small project for a Lattice ice40hx8k dev board. However, the programming stage fails with:

```
iceprog counter.bin
Can't find iCE FTDI USB device (vedor_id 0x0403, device_id 0x6010).
ABORT.
```

It appears to be a permission problem, because if I run the programming stage as root, it works fine.

I created this udef file as part of the installation process:

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/53-lattice-ftdi.rules 
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}
```

and also this file:

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/50-lattice-ftdi.rules 
# FTDI USB-Serial
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6010", GROUP="users", MODE="0666"
```

Can someone help me fix this non-root user programming permission problem?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `/etc/udev/rules.d/53-lattice-ftdi.rules` file seems to be truncated for some reason. The contents of this file should be:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="0403", ATTR{idProduct}=="6010", MODE:="666"
```

After fixing that file, and disconnecting and reconnecting the device, you should be able to program the FPGA as normal user without `sudo`.